# How to get a span and an input to stay on the same line and scroll in constrained div?

Tags: html, css

I want to get a `span` and an `input` to stay on the same line in a `div` of fixed with so that the `div` is scrollable if overflow happens.

Here is my attempt:

http://jsbin.com/yogimawo/1/edit

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    #main {
      overflow-x: auto;
      width: 30px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='main'>
    <span>abc</span>
    <span>efesf</span>
    <input type='text'></input>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not the solution but `<input type='text'></input>` is invalid HTML, it's `<input type='text' />` you're after.

Answer (score 3):

`white-space: nowrap;` is what you are after :)

[Jsbin example!](http://jsbin.com/xudugoti/4/edit)

CSS

```
#main {
  overflow: scroll; /* for CSS3 lacking browsers */
  overflow: scroll hidden;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#main span, #main input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="main">
      <span>abc</span>
      <span>efesf</span>
      <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Although this is a viable solution, the problem is this will not be fully cross browser compatible. For instance Firefox 30/win will not show the scrollbar, so you'll loose whatever overflows the container element. Not sure if this is an unknown FF bug or not, but this was present in previous versions as well

Comment: Is this the `overflow-x`? I have updated my answer. Browsers receive scroll on x and y axis if they do not support the CSS3 rule. CSS3 supporting browsers receive just the x axis scroll. This should be cross browser compatible :)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the `overflow-x`. Firefox will show the elements inline as expected, but even though the contained elements will exceed the container width, it (of some reason) won't apply the scrollbar / scroll arrows. It's always one browser messing up, isn't it..?

Comment: Maybe :) the good thing about Firefox and Chrome is that users tend to use the latest version as it is not tied to the OS like IE. It works in the later versions of Firefox, Chrome. It works in IE... I would say it's cross browser compatible :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should just use simple css float & display code.

```
span { float: left; display: block; width: 33%; }
input { float: left; display: block; width: 33%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the `white-space: nowrap;` rule.

Assuming your span and input elements are `display: inline`:

```
#main {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```